# How to pass the data from Browser to another activity?

Tags: android

Is it possible to pass the data from Browser to Explicit Activity?

Ex: I have gmail open in the Browser. One of the emails contains `href(http://xxx/Test.pdf)` document. I want to pass directly the href(URL) info to my Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An activity can be started by passing Appropriate intent . so If calling app want to launch your activity then only it will be possible and as gmail is not your own app and you dont have code so you can't do this .